# Why sometimes I have voice but no data on a GSM network?

Tags: gsm, cellphone, data, network, internet

From what I understand, both voice and data are using the same antenna (At least 3G).

Sometimes in a remote area, I have plenty of signal but no data service.

Is it possible some cell towers don't offer data (voice only)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GSM by itself does not support data, just voice (even SMS is put ontop of GSM). Data service, beyond the 9600baud CSD (which doesn't seem to be supported by most phones/mobile providers anymore) requires the availability of GPRS or EDGE. Although both systems are very old, depending on where you are, there are still base stations around that only support GSM without any data service.